# some css not working while running ionic 4 app on ios simulator

Tags: css, angular, ionic4

All css works fine when i run ionic app on android but ion-content background image does not display when i run the app in Xcode simulator(ios).

I have already tried to change the path of the image. Still then it is not working.

```
<ion-content class="home">
```

here is the css files

```
.home {
 --background: transparent; 
 background-image: url('assets/img/bg.png');
```

}

Comment: HI, have you solved the issue? I'm facing the same issue. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

One quick idea is to base64 encode the image to remove the question about the path.

This will let you see if the rule is being overridden for some reason (https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/).

But the best thing you can do is to investigate what is going on by using the remote debugging techniques:

[Debugging iOS Apps - iOS Development - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/ios#debugging-ios-apps)

Basically you can run the app and then use the Safari dev tools window to inspect it just like you would with a normal website. This lets you see the exact CSS cascade thats being applied.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Safari dev tools window to inspect i found out that the resourced could not be loaded.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwLIi.png